# Have SQL calculate the sum for an entire column - Having trouble grouping I believe

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sum

The attached picture displays the result set, and I will leave my code below - why am I not able to calculate the sum of the entire `viewTotal` column within each cell? I want each cell underneath the `viewTotal` column to read `4`.

I would imagine that this is some kind of grouping issue although I can't find anything specific on the web in regards to which columns need to be grouped. **It is important that all three rows remain - I don't want to return just one row.** Perhaps this criteria makes what I'm trying to do more difficult?

Thank you,
Evan

[image: Result Preview]

```
Select topic_id, topic_subject, SUM(topicViews) as viewTotal, replyCount From
                        (
                        Select 
                            T.topic_id, T.topic_subject, Count(distinct Tvt.id) as topicViews, Count(Distinct R.reply_id) as replyCount, R.reply_id, R.reply_topic
                            From topic T                                                                         
                            LEFT JOIN topic_view_tracker Tvt ON
                                T.topic_id = Tvt.topic_id   
                            LEFT Join reply R ON
                                T.topic_id = R.reply_topic
                            Where   
                            T.topic_by = 10
                            Group By T.topic_id) B
                        Group By topic_id
                        Order by replyCount DESC
```

Sample records:

**TOPIC** Table

```
╔══════════╦════════════════════════════╦══════════╗
║ TOPIC_ID ║       TOPIC_SUBJECT        ║ TOPIC_BY ║
╠══════════╬════════════════════════════╬══════════╣
║       25 ║ School police in the night ║       10 ║
║       29 ║ The first topic, enjoy it  ║       10 ║
║       30 ║ This is a normal title...  ║       10 ║
╚══════════╩════════════════════════════╩══════════╝
```

**TOPIC_VIEW_TRACKER** Table

```
╔════╦════════════╦══════════╗
║ ID ║  USER_IP   ║ TOPIC_ID ║
╠════╬════════════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║ xx.xx.xx.x ║       25 ║
║  2 ║ xx.xx.xx.x ║       25 ║
║  3 ║ xx.xxx.xxx ║       29 ║
║  4 ║ xxx.xx.xx  ║       30 ║
╚════╩════════════╩══════════╝
```

**REPLY** Table

```
╔══════════╦═════════════╗
║ REPLY_ID ║ REPLY_TOPIC ║
╠══════════╬═════════════╣
║        1 ║          25 ║
║        2 ║          29 ║
╚══════════╩═════════════╝
```

> Expected output (example):

```
topic_id       topic subject                          view total   reply count
29         The first topic, enjoy it                    4            5
25          school police in the night                  4            4
30          this is a normal title for a topic ...      4            0
```

Comment: can you give sample records?

Comment: Sure what exactly are you looking for? Do you want more data from the tables? The thing is, the picture I posted is the result from the sub-select so I figured that would be enough.

Comment: Yeah, I need sample data even if you supply 2-3 records for each table and your desired result `:D` it would help a lot

Comment: Sure, give me just a minute to compile something for you.

Comment: If this is associated with application code like php or coldfusion or something like that, you could use it to get your total.

Comment: @DanBracuk No it's not associated with an app. 
jw- hopefully that's what you were looking for. Let me know if I can help out anymore

Comment: why is the reply count for `29` is `5`? and the `viewTotal` is the total count for all records on table `topic_view_tracker`?

Comment: @JW. I don't understand your first question. Regarding your second question, yes, as long as the topic_id column matches up with the topic_id at hand, then the views all count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  x.*, 
        COALESCE(y.viewTotal, 0) viewTotal,
        COALESCE(z.replyCount, 0) replyCount
FROM    topic x
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  a.topic_by, COUNT(b.topic_ID) viewTotal
            FROM    topic a
                    LEFT JOIN topic_view_tracker b
                        ON a.topic_ID = b.topic_ID
            GROUP   BY a.topic_by
        ) y ON x.topic_by = y.topic_by
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  reply_topic, COUNT(*) replyCount
            FROM    reply
            GROUP   BY reply_topic
        ) z ON  x.topic_ID = z.reply_topic
WHERE   x.topic_by = 10
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fda2e/2)

OUTPUT (*based on the records provided*)

```
╔══════════╦════════════════════════════╦══════════╦═══════════╦════════════╗
║ TOPIC_ID ║       TOPIC_SUBJECT        ║ TOPIC_BY ║ VIEWTOTAL ║ REPLYCOUNT ║
╠══════════╬════════════════════════════╬══════════╬═══════════╬════════════╣
║       25 ║ School police in the night ║       10 ║         4 ║          1 ║
║       29 ║ The first topic, enjoy it  ║       10 ║         4 ║          1 ║
║       30 ║ This is a normal title...  ║       10 ║         4 ║          0 ║
╚══════════╩════════════════════════════╩══════════╩═══════════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: I see you have it all setup and working on that server - for some reason it's just not taking very well over on mine - no error or anything, just, no output. I see nothing in the error log either, very strange. Give me a minute to investigate what's going on. Thank you though very much.

Comment: I got it to throw this error:

Unknown column 'y.topic_id' in 'on clause'. Just checked, the same error was thrown when I tried to run it directly in PHPMyAdmin

Comment: oh, it was a typo. sorry for that, it should be `x.topic_ID`. run my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks man, I'm sure it's working - I need to modify the code a bit to work with the prepared statement. Btw, what is the method of code you used there called? The "x y and z" - I've never seen this before (granted, I'm quite new to SQL)...

Comment: @Evan hehe forgive me for using such `ALIAS`es like that (*because I'm used to*). They are like nicknames for the tables.

Comment: oh you know what, I didn't even see the part "topic x" etc. - it slipped right past me :)

Comment: hehe so instead of using `topic` you use `x`. This are very helpful when you have longer table names.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26126/discussion-between-evan-and-jw)

Answer (score 0):

If you need the total views to be repeated on each row you need to use this:

```
Select topic_id, topic_subject, (SELECT Count(distinct id) FROM topic_view_tracker WHERE topic_id = B.topic_id)) AS viewTotal, replyCount From
                        (
                        Select 
                            T.topic_id, T.topic_subject, Count(distinct Tvt.id) as topicViews, Count(Distinct R.reply_id) as replyCount, R.reply_id, R.reply_topic
                            From topic T                                                                         
                            LEFT JOIN topic_view_tracker Tvt ON
                                T.topic_id = Tvt.topic_id   
                            LEFT Join reply R ON
                                T.topic_id = R.reply_topic
                            Where   
                            T.topic_by = 10
                            Group By T.topic_id) B
                        Group By topic_id
                        Order by replyCount DESC
```

But I do not see the reason for this, honestly. You can easily execute `SELECT Count(distinct id) FROM topic_view_tracker WHERE topic_id = 10` separately and then execute the rest of your query, omitting `topic_view_tracker` from it altogether

Comment: When I ran your code I actually got the same results as when I ran it - the sums were being grouped by topic_id - so each row in the column has only a piece of the entire sum. I will take your advice into consideration though as I'm sure that's a better idea. I was just worried that more SQL statements would mean a slower loading time - is that not true?